# Segment control doesn't change button

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I have code of segment control:

```
-(IBAction)sectionswitch:(id)sender {

    if (control.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(call1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [button setTitle:@"+000000000000" forState: UIControlStateNormal] ;
    }

    if (control.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(call2:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [button setTitle:@"+111111111111" forState: UIControlStateNormal] ;
    }

}


- (IBAction)call1:(id)sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://+000000000000"]];
}

- (IBAction)call2:(id)sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://+111111111111"]];
}
```

But when i change segment control button always call to +111111111111 
How to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you toggle the segmented control your code **adds** a target/action to the button. Note it **adds**, not replaces.

So when you toggle from +000 to +111 and back, the button now has **both** target/actions added, and will call both `call1:` and `call2:` methods.

Before adding the target/action you should remove the previous target/action added to the button with `removeTarget:action:forControlEvents:`.

Comment: Good to hear! Please remember to accept answers that helped solve your problem.